# RegEx match everything between 2 characters only if at least 3 characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to match all characters between "xAA" and "xFF" but only if theres at least 4 characters between those. Is there a simple way to do this with RegEx?

For example, xAA-12345-xFF should be matched but xAA-1-xFF should be ignored.

My RegEx currently looks like this:

```
"(?<=\xAA).*(?=\xFF)"
```

this does match everything between those characters, but i can't find a way on how to only match if at least 4 characters between them, can someone help me?

Comment: Why escape `x` if you want to match an `x` letter? Please provide some test cases with real world examples.

Comment: Is there always `-<digits>-` between `xAA` and `xFF`? Then use `(?<=xAA-)\d{4,}(?=-xFF)`

Comment: I should have explained this in more detail. I am receiving data from a Serialport, starting with Hex AA und ending with Hex FF. I want to match everything in between with at least 4 characters because theres also a load of "AA 00 FF" strings which i want to filter out.

Comment: Does `(?<=\xAA\s*)(?:(?!\xAA).)*?(?=\s*\xFF)` work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty hack could be:

```
"xAA....*xFF"
```

This requires three (`...`) characters followed by 0 or more (`.*`).

Comment: This won't work for strings with multiple matches since it will start matching from the leftmost `\xAA`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I think that should still be valid regarding to the question above? Why should that be a problem with multiple matches? But I simplified the Regex, but maybe I did not fully understand the source and expected match behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`xAA\S{4,}xFF`

`\S{4,}` matches at least 4 non whitespace characters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W8PqyV/1)

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=xAA-)[0-9]{4,}(?=\-xFF)`
retracts **12345** from `xAA-12345-xFF` in case there are only digits

`(?<=xAA-)[0-9a-zA-Z]{4,}(?=\-xFF)` if letters or digits are possible

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qWsgxy/1)